# Does each item in a QStandardItemModel have a unique QModelIndex?

Tags: python, pyqt, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QStandardItem Model with QStandardItems that look like this

- USA

  - Population
  - Capital city
- France

  - Population
  - Capital city

When a user doubleClicked signal is sent by the user, I can get a QModelIndex with a data() method so that if they double-click on, say, "Population", then data() will return "Population".

My question. Does the QModelIndex distinguish between, say, the QStandardItems belonging to USA from those belonging to france? Is there a more elegant solution than stuff like model_index.parent().parent()... ? An ideal solution would be a function like

```
def get_standard_item(model: QStandardItemModel, index: QModelIndex) -> QStandardItem:
...
```

[edit] - I found this in the QModelIndex class documentation:

"QModelIndex::internalId() - Returns a quintptr used by the model to associate the index with the internal data structure."

Can this be used somehow to fetch the corresponding QStandardItem?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking how to get a QStandardItem from a QModelIndex?

Comment: `item = index.model().itemFromIndex(index)` (or perhaps `item = model.itemFromIndex(index)`, if you have a local reference to the right model).

Comment: It's also unclear to me. The ```QModelIndex``` is just an index to an item, a lightweight object with short-time life. It's a container for the row, column and internal pointer(in the C++ world). Of course two indices for two different items are different to each other.

Comment: @musicamante I was wondering if each item in an item model has a unique index, in the same way each element in, say, an array of floats has a unique index.

Comment: @relent95 I want to know how to fetch an item from a model using the index. A QModelIndex has row() and column() and data(), but you can see that in the above example, both instances of "Population" will have the same row and column and data. How does a QModelIndex distinguish them?

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks! Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @DJames they have unique "indexes" but they are not simple array indexes: they are always a combination of row, column and, most importantly, a unique *pointer* (to a specific object or even to a numerical id), so that you can have the same combination of row `x` and column `y` **but** with a different identifier, which is what tells the model (and connected views) their actual position in the model structure; that pointer can be considered almost like a `z` coordinate that allows to know the real position of two points that share identical x and y coordinates, and that's exactly what »

Comment: @DJames » `itemFromIndex()` uses to get a QStandardItem from a QModelIndex. Note that that's exactly what I asked you and what you finally wanted, if you want to know the internal mechanism of model indexes that's a different story (and different question too). I suggest you to take your time to carefully read the [Qt model/view programming documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: @DJames Consider a list or tree model with only single column. For a list model, the row number of an item is an index of the item in the list. For a tree model, the row number of an item is an index of the item in the list of its sibling items(children of its parent item). Mostly the internal pointer of a ```QModelIndex``` instance contains a reference to a node of the tree and it contains the information of its parent and child nodes.